# Conjunctive Normal Form (CNF) of a propositional formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

[image]

These are my notes for Discrete Math. I'm having trouble understanding how to convert the given formulae at the end into CNF. The example seems to have skipped the steps and jumped straight to the answer :(

Answer (score 0):

This is just the distributive law in Propositional Logic.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic